# Making a window pop under in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup

I have a button that needs to open a new window as a popup (under the parent page). In IE/Firefox, it works fine, but in chrome the popup appears over (on top of) the parent window.

Please suggest a fix.

use case/eg: Well, for eg if you see kayak.com or any travel website, you have the ability to search on other websites too..I want to do something similar so need the pop under...

Code: I am using a window.open(.......).blur(), but for some reason it isnt working in chrome.

Comment: @TheifMaster: I can easily justify a pop-up. Not a pop-under.

Comment: Well, for eg if you see kayak.com or any travel website, you have the ability to search on other websites too..I want to do something similar so need the pop under...

Comment: @ideate: Kayak uses popups for this functionality, not pop-unders.

Comment: I am using a window.open(.......).blur(), but for some reason it isnt working in chrome.

Comment: @Robert: Yeah. They use pop-unders for ads, *exactly* the kind of thing that I think we're all saying we don't want to help achieve. Not for the search.

Comment: Pop-unders are sooo annoying. Way to go Chrome, one more reason to use you!

Comment: I must admit I get really tired of the answer "Don't do this as it's annoying to me" answers or comments.  A question like "How can I create a popunder in chrome" is indeed valid.  If your code of ethics prevents you from answering, then I appreciate (and probably share your ethics) but there is no Capt. Morality badge here. (By  the way @ideate, the short answer is you cannot.  The long answer is, like all long answers, anything is possible given infinite time and resources.) /rant (Reflecting my morality I upvoted @T.J.s comment)

Comment: @Jason I see where you're coming from and I agree in principle, but as long as this doesn't get downvoted (which neither the question nor any possible answers should be, as it is a valid question!), I don't see why people shouldn't be allowed to air their annoyedness.

Comment: @Pekka you're probably right but since everyone else was up on their soapbox I decided to drag mine out as well.

Comment: @Pekka: Sadly, Chrome doesn't defeat kayak.com's (or travelocity.com's) pop-under ads. :-( @Jason: I agree, and I've posted how to do pop-ups here on StackOverflow, because there are lots of valid use cases for them. Perhaps I'm just being cranky, but in the absense of a genuine use case, I'm just not inclined to help with pop *unders*. Perhaps I go too far suggesting others shouldn't, fair 'nuff. :-)

Comment: @Jason yeah, and your comment is a good counter-weight.

Comment: @ T.J. oooh i didn't know that (off to investigate travelocity.com in chrome to find out how they perform the evil) ;)

Comment: Coming back to my question....Can someone actually suggest how kayak/travelocity is doing it?

Comment: @ideate kayak use flash to open multiple popup under

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I take back my comment, is possible.

The following worked for me.  (tested latest production chrome)

```
var url = "yourURL.html";
window.open(url, "s", "width= 640, height= 480, left=0, top=0, resizable=yes, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no").blur();
window.focus();
```

Like all things, if you annoy your visitors you will have less visitors.

Comment: +1 because it answers the question, nevertheless the fact remains that nobody should use pop-unders.

Comment: That works in Chrome. Does anyone know a solution that works in Firefox too? I had something that worked for a while, but seems to be broken with the latest update.

Comment: You have resizable=yes and resizable=no at the same time in your window features ;) make up your mind

Comment: I have a site where I want the user to be able to submit a form and trigger the download of a large file.  I set the form's action to "_blank", and the data it has to process before the download is huge, so the new tab is created and hangs for maybe 20 seconds.  I want the tab in case of an error page, and so they can continue doing other work on the main window.  I think a pop-under for this download tab would be a perfectly good and legitimate use for pop-unders.  However, this code doesn't seem to work anymore (on Chrome anyway).

Comment: Does not work for me on Edge 96.0.1054.41

Answer (score 4):

```
function makePopunder(pUrl) {
    var _parent = (top != self && typeof (top["document"]["location"].toString()) === "string") ? top : self;
    var mypopunder = null;
    var pName = (Math["floor"]((Math["random"]() * 1000) + 1));
    var pWidth = window["innerWidth"];
    var pHeight = window["innerHeight"];
    var pPosX = window["screenX"];
    var pPosY = window["screenY"];
    var pWait = 3600;
    pWait = (pWait * 1000);
    var pCap = 50000;
    var todayPops = 0;
    var cookie = "_.mypopunder";
    var browser = function () {
        var n = navigator["userAgent"]["toLowerCase"]();
        var b = {
            webkit: /webkit/ ["test"](n),
            mozilla: (/mozilla/ ["test"](n)) && (!/(compatible|webkit)/ ["test"](n)),
            chrome: /chrome/ ["test"](n),
            msie: (/msie/ ["test"](n)) && (!/opera/ ["test"](n)),
            firefox: /firefox/ ["test"](n),
            safari: (/safari/ ["test"](n) && !(/chrome/ ["test"](n))),
            opera: /opera/ ["test"](n)
        };
        b["version"] = (b["safari"]) ? (n["match"](/.+(?:ri)[\/: ]([\d.]+)/) || [])[1] : (n["match"](/.+(?:ox|me|ra|ie)[\/: ]([\d.]+)/) || [])[1];
        return b;
    }();

    function isCapped() {
        try {
            todayPops = Math["floor"](document["cookie"]["split"](cookie + "Cap=")[1]["split"](";")[0]);
        } catch (err) {};
        return (pCap <= todayPops || document["cookie"]["indexOf"](cookie + "=") !== -1);
    };

    function doPopunder(pUrl, pName, pWidth, pHeight, pPosX, pPosY) {
        if (isCapped()) {
            return;
        };
        var sOptions = "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=yes,statusbar=yes,menubar=no,resizable=1,width=" + pWidth.toString() + ",height=" + pHeight.toString() + ",screenX=" + pPosX + ",screenY=" + pPosY;
        document["onclick"] = function (e) {
            if (isCapped() || window["pop_clicked"] == 1 || pop_isRightButtonClicked(e)) {
                //return;
            };
            window["pop_clicked"] = 1;
            mypopunder = _parent["window"]["open"](pUrl, pName, sOptions);
            if (mypopunder) {
                var now = new Date();
                document["cookie"] = cookie + "=1;expires=" + new Date(now["setTime"](now["getTime"]() + pWait))["toGMTString"]() + ";path=/";
                now = new Date();
                document["cookie"] = cookie + "Cap=" + (todayPops + 1) + ";expires=" + new Date(now["setTime"](now["getTime"]() + (84600 * 1000)))["toGMTString"]() + ";path=/";
                pop2under();
            };
        };
    };

    function pop2under() {
        try {
            mypopunder["blur"]();
            mypopunder["opener"]["window"]["focus"]();
            window["self"]["window"]["blur"]();
            window["focus"]();
            if (browser["firefox"]) {
                openCloseWindow();
            };
            if (browser["webkit"]) {
                openCloseTab();
            };
        } catch (e) {};
    };

    function openCloseWindow() {
        var ghost = window["open"]("about:blank");
        ghost["focus"]();
        ghost["close"]();
    };

    function openCloseTab() {
        var ghost = document["createElement"]("a");
        ghost["href"] = "about:blank";
        ghost["target"] = "PopHelper";
        document["getElementsByTagName"]("body")[0]["appendChild"](ghost);
        ghost["parentNode"]["removeChild"](ghost);
        var clk = document["createEvent"]("MouseEvents");
        clk["initMouseEvent"]("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
        ghost["dispatchEvent"](clk);
        window["open"]("about:blank", "PopHelper")["close"]();
    };

    function pop_isRightButtonClicked(e) {
        var rightclick = false;
        e = e || window["event"];
        if (e["which"]) {
            rightclick = (e["which"] == 3);
        } else {
            if (e["button"]) {
                rightclick = (e["button"] == 2);
            };
        };
        return rightclick;
    };
    if (isCapped()) {
        return;
    } else {
        doPopunder(pUrl, pName, pWidth, pHeight, pPosX, pPosY);
    };
}

makePopunder("http://www.yourdomain.com/");
```

Comment: Code seems to be from https://github.com/tuki/js-popunder which says the project is abandoned.

Comment: Looks good. Also how to open the popunder automatically once page loads

Answer (score 4):

The end of popunder is here.
Chrome closed it yesterday.

Comment: Could you please explain more?  Or link to proof?

Answer (score 3):

This is the fix you can use for Chrome (tested on lastest v.40 on 29/01/2015).
*This won't open a window popup but a new tab and <strike>keeps on main tab focused</strike>(no more keeps focus on main tab on chrome v.43>).*

To avoid popup blocker, you need user interaction, use specifically `mousedown` or `mouseup` event, `click` will throw a popup blocker warning.

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", tabUnder);

function tabUnder() {
    var a = document.createElement("a"),
        e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    a.href = "http://testit.com"; //the URL of 'popup' tab
    e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(e);
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", tabUnder);
}
```

### -jsFiddle-

Answer (score 2):

You could also leave the popup behind, like this:

```
var MINUTE_MILLISECONDS = 60000;
var now = new Date().getTime();

if (!localStorage.t || now > parseInt(localStorage.t) + MINUTE_MILLISECONDS) {
    var date = new Date();
    localStorage.t = now;
    window.location.href = "http://dgsprb.blogspot.com/";
    window.open(window.document.URL, "_blank");
}
```

This way the new content is left behind on the current tab, opening a new tab with the original window content. Works pretty much like a pop under, provided you can afford to reload the current window. You also ensure that the popup won't be shown more than once per minute.

Answer (score 1):

The misterious code of @dixie works for me on firefox, I.E, and almost Chrome (it doesn't focus on the main window but on the pop-up).

To make it perfectly work on Google Chrome, I simply added this to regain focus:

```
path = window.document.URL;
window.open(path,"_self");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** - doesn't work anymore

---

**Previous answer:**

```
window.open('http://google.com','','height=500,width=500');
window.open().close();
```

Don't use popunders for evil

Answer (score 0):

This code works up to Chrome 65:

```
function just_open() {
    postMessage([...arguments]);
}
window.onmessage = function({data}){
    return open(...data);
}
function openunder() {
    just_open([...arguments]);
    window.open().close();
}
```

Where openunder is just like open() except:

- no return value
- No Chrome 65+, uses https://crbug.com/833148