# Javascript popup under code?

Tags: javascript, popup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making a window pop under in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261784/making-a-window-pop-under-in-chrome)

i want to make popup but running in background (popup under).
After open popup, the focus will change to the parent window.

i saw it on kat.ph but couldn't get the code.

```
object.blur();
window.focus();
```

didn't work these days anymore :(

Comment: Please don't :( Nobody uses popunders for anything legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

In the popup's onload say:

```
window.blur();
window.opener.focus();
```

Comment: won't work with google chrome :| and the one who tell me duplicate , that's solution won't work too!