# Open new window in background on

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window-object

I'm trying to open new windows in the background in **Google Chrome version 62.0.3202.94**. I run the code by typing in Notepad and copy-pasting into <kbd>F12</kbd> Developer Console.

This is the code I've tried so far, adapted from various Google search results:

```
var url = "https://stackoverflow.com/";

function test1(){
    var w = window.open(url);
    w.blur();
    window.focus();
}

function test2(){
    window.open(url);
    window.open().close();
}

function test3(){
    window.open(url, "s", "width= 640, height= 480, left=0, top=0, resizable=yes, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no").blur();
    window.focus();
}
```

And I typed `test1()` and `test2()` and `test3()` and hit Enter without achieving what I desired: The new page just opens and acquires the focus.

Any chance I could do that?

---

<sup>Note the emphasis on browser and version.</sup>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a window pop under in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261784/making-a-window-pop-under-in-chrome)

Comment: @Kos Those answers don't work on Chrome 62.

Answer (score 0):

This would only work for opening new windows in the background, not new tabs

```
window.open('http://google.com','','height=500,width=500');
window.open().close();
```

Don't use popunders for evil