# Window.open on Chrome - lowered by default

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup

I'm trying to figure out how I could use window.open to open a window in Chrome without having this window displayed on top of the active window.

I'm using this:

```
_Top.window.open(myURL,myWindowID,'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=1,statusbar=1,menubar=0,alwaysLowered=yes,z-lock="yes",resizable=1,top=800,left='+pxLeft+',width='+myWidth+',height='+myHeight);
```

I'm trying with alwaysLowered, z-lock, ... but when used on Chrome, the new windows comes on top of the active window. It works in Firefox and IE but not on Chrome.

I also use:

```
_Top.window.blur();
```

Is there a parameter to achieve this or should I use something else for Chrome?

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: Can you create http://jsfiddle.net/ that we can check or test in different browsers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a window pop under in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261784/making-a-window-pop-under-in-chrome)